# netbeans 7.3 add git to project

Tags: netbeans-7

I have multiple projects in netbeans. Some of these projects are version controlled using cvs and others using git. When I change something in the project that is using git, a .cvsignore file is created automatically. But I don't want the project to use git.

Secondly, I created the project in netbeans and then went to terminal and did a git init. There is no term/version control decoration on the project but when I do a team -> git -> initialize, netbeans says that "Selected file is already part of a Git repository.". Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. That means someone already added your project to Git. (At least tried). 
If you want to get rid and add your project to your own Git repo , search for .git files inside the project and delete them. 
After that start the process again.